# extract replacement list with conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a long list of lists of values and replacement rules as:

```
list = {
 {{0.5, {r0 -> 0.1, a -> 2.3}}, {2.0, {r0 -> 0.8, a -> 0.4}}, {1.2, {r0 -> 1.1, a -> 0.7}}}
 {{4.2, {r0 -> 5.1, a -> 0.9}}, {0.1, {r0 -> 1.3, a -> 7.4}}, {1.0, {r0 -> 3.3, a -> 0.4}}}
 {{1.0, {r0 -> 1.1, a -> 1.9}}, {0.7, {r0 -> 1.2, a -> 2.2}}, {0.1, {r0 -> 4.8, a -> 3.2}}}
   (*AND SO ON till more than 1000 lists*)
}
```

I would like to make another list, with the second elements of the previous list, such that the first one is the minimum of the each row... I mean, something like

```
{ {r0 -> 0.1, a -> 2.3}
, {r0 -> 1.3, a -> 7.4}
, {r0 -> 4.8, a -> 3.2}    
, (*...*)
}
```

Comment: the minimum has to be the first element, not in the replacement list; in the last row is
{0.1, {r0 -> 4.8, a -> 3.2}}

Comment: it worked great, thanks @Kuba

Answer (score 4):

```
Map[First@Cases[#, {x_ /; x == Min[First @@@ #[[All, 1]]], pat : __ } :> 
 pat , Infinity] &, list]
```

or in a more succint and better way proposed by Kuba:

```
Last@*First@*MinimalBy[First]/@ list
```

another method that works (suggested by pfactors):

```
Last@First@Sort@# &/@ list
```

Comment: Probably worth noting Ali that your version (although probably slower) would work in MMA < 10.  As a side note I think `Last@First@Sort@# & /@ list` might work as well.

Answer (score 3):

In:

```
Clear[a, r0, list]
list = {{{0.5, {r0 -> 0.1, a -> 2.3}}, {2.0, {r0 -> 0.8, 
     a -> 0.4}}, {1.2, {r0 -> 1.1, a -> 0.7}}}, {{4.2, {r0 -> 5.1, 
     a -> 0.9}}, {0.1, {r0 -> 1.3, a -> 7.4}}, {1.0, {r0 -> 3.3, 
     a -> 0.4}}}, {{1.0, {r0 -> 1.1, a -> 1.9}}, {0.7, {r0 -> 1.2, 
     a -> 2.2}}, {0.1, {r0 -> 4.8, a -> 3.2}}}};

list // Map@MinimalBy@First // Last @@@ # &
```

Out:

```
{{r0 -> 0.1, a -> 2.3}, {r0 -> 1.3, a -> 7.4}, {r0 -> 4.8, a -> 3.2}}
```